# TableViewCell misplaced upon scrolling

Tags: ios, tableview, uitableview

This is what i have in mind. There is a `TableView`. Each cell has a button. When i tap on it, the button gets removed and a `ProgressView` is subviewed instead. The problem is that when i have not scrolled the table everything seems to work fine. But upon scrolling, everything gets messed up and the buttons and `ProgressView`s order gets all mixed up.

Here is the code:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
// Download Button
DownloadButtonCell=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 48, 48)];
[DownloadButtonCell setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"download.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
DownloadButtonCell.tag=111;
[DownloadButtonCell addTarget:self action:@selector(startDownload:)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:DownloadButtonCell];
return cell;
}
```

And this is the download method where the download button is removed and the progress view is shown instead:

```
-(void)startDownload:(id)sender
{
CGPoint buttonPosition=[sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableview];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);

LLACircularProgressView *progressView=[[LLACircularProgressView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 40, 25, 25)];
progressView.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[progressView addTarget:self action:@selector(stopDownload:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[[[tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] viewWithTag:111]removeFromSuperview];    
[[[tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]contentView] addSubview:progressView];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[mp3Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
NSString *pdfName = [[idArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringByAppendingString:@".mp3"];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:pdfName];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {

    progressView.progress=(float)totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToRead;
}];
[operation start];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at overriding the method prepareForReuse in your tableviewcell subclass and making sure that the cell starts with a consistent state there.

It looks like you always add the download button in the cellForRowAtIndexpath method, which means when cell gets reused, the download button is always added which means that each cell could end up having multiple download buttons added to them... when you remove the button in order to add the progress bar it's not clear which button you would be removing in that case (this is vaguely defined in the apple docs).

It also looks like that if there is already a progress view added to a cell that is about to be reused that it would not be removed so you would have a download button on top of a progress view after cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
//DownloadableTableViewCell.h
@interface DownloadableTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (assign, nonatomic, getter=isDownloading) BOOL downloading;
@end

//DownloadabletableViewCell.m
@interface DownloadableTableViewCell()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *downloadButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *progressView;
@end

@implementation
-(id)initWithStyeleBlahblah{
   self = [super initWithStyleBlahBlah];
   if (self){
      //init download button, init progress view.

      //add download button to view.
   }
   return self;
}

-(void)setDownloading:(BOOL)downloading{
   _downloading = downloading;
   if (_downloading){
      //add progress view to contentview.
      //remove download button.
   }
   else{
      //add button to contentView;
      //remove progress view;
   }
}


-(void)prepareForReuse{
   [super prepareForReuse];
   self.downloading = NO;
}
```

Comment: Orite thanks, that was what i suspected myself but didnt know how to correct it. do u have any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: you just have to "do the right thing."  for your case.  I would start by sublcassing UITableViewCell and then holding onto your download button and progress view as @property (strong, nonatomic) DownloadButtonCell *... inside of it.  Then when you change state remove and add the already instantiated view in the tableviewcell subclass.  in your tableviewcell sublcass then use -(void)prepareForReuse to reset the state to the correct one.

Comment: sorry, enter added the comment instead of adding a new line.

Comment: added code sample.  may not compile just totally made it up as I went, but it's the shape of the problem... then all your complicated view creation, adding can be simply   find the cell, set the .downloading property to the right value.

Comment: didnt work! I exactly know whats wrong with my code but dunno how to fix it. I have trouble using the cell reuse properly.

Comment: @devdev101 can you gist up your code and post a link?

Comment: not really, im have a contract for this app and it requires privacy of the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Your cellForRowAtIndexPath is getting called every time it gets on the screen. You are also creating the download button there so every time the cell goes off-screen and then gets back on the screen, the download button is created anew.

Comment: @rashidasgari, i updated my answer with some code, my initial response got cut off because enter == add_comment and i was trying to insert a new line.